# DataSet and SQL Dynamically Like

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with the nvarchar field. My app has a search page, and a user can type some words into the search box.

I used a DataSet in my app. I want to make an SQL statement with a dynamic Like  in the where clause such as

```
"WHERE field1 like '%string1%' AND field1 like '%string2%' AND ..."
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) in C#.  For nvarchar you omit the quotes with the @ variable.

Comment: @mSafdel do you want to use LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dataview or use select command in datatable.

Dtataview syntax :-

```
dtEditSitePages = new DataView(dtEditSitePages,"field1 like '%t%'","",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
```

//dtEditSitePages is datatable on which filter will fire

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make a procedure which accepts user input like,

   Create Procedure Search ( @serch1 varchar(200), @search2 varchar(200) as begin

   .......
2. In the body just type select * from tbl_name where field1 like "%search1%" and field2 like "%search1%"

Go forward with this. May be it will help you.

**Also you can try full text indexing in your Database which is very helpful**